# Azure app service can't run Aspnet core app due to unexpected TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, masstransit, .net-5

I build an ASP.net core application that runs well locally.
But when I deploy it to azure, I get a 500.30 error.
What I did was:

- open Kudu,
- open a powershell window,
- navigate to the wwwroot folder
- Run dotnet Myapp.dll
- Then the error appeared to be that my app couldn't initialize the error is shown below:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MassTransit.Serialization.JsonMessageSerializer' threw an exception.
> ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
> at MassTransit.Serialization.JsonMessageSerializer..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MassTransit.Configuration.SerializationConfiguration..ctor()
> at MassTransit.Configuration.EndpointConfiguration..ctor(ITopologyConfiguration topology)
> at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Configuration.ServiceBusEndpointConfiguration..ctor(IServiceBusTopologyConfiguration topologyConfiguration)
> at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Configuration.ServiceBusBusConfiguration..ctor(IServiceBusTopologyConfiguration topologyConfiguration)

This error is completely weird because I installed and updated Newtonsoft json in the project that contains MassTransit. The version it points to is version Newtonsoft.json 12.0.3
And on my local PC, I don't have this problem.
I'm actually targetting DotNet5
Can someone help ? please

Comment: This might be a deployment error. Can you find the NewtonSoft dll in Kudu?

Comment: Newtonsoft dll is actually there.

Comment: What happens if you start the app in the portal? Same thing?

Comment: Finally, after updating newtonsoft json the preview version 13, the problem got solved. Though browsing to my app's URL still shows a 500.30 forbidden error, running it from kudu doesn't cause any problem

Comment: MassTransit uses Newtonsoft v11, and I believe it works with 12. Not sure about other versions.